# Validate a form with jQuery Validator plugin but trigger it from a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-validate

All,
I'm trying to use the jQuery Form Validator (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). However I'd like to be able to click a link to do the validation and then submit the form if everything is ok. Does anyone know how to do this? Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally possible. The plugin docs even [give an example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid), which I've modified a little bit to submit instead of alert:

```js
$("#myform").validate();
$("a.check").click(function() {
  if ($("#myform").valid()) {
    $("#myform").submit();
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: **You do not need to use `.valid()` in this case**, since the Validate plugin will continue to properly block `.submit()` of an invalid form.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work the same as the accepted answer but with all the redundancy removed.  *(There is no need to use `.valid()` to check the form, since the Validate plugin will continue to properly block an invalid form.)*

- Use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to block the default behaviors of the anchor element.

  ```
  $("#myform").validate();                // initialize plugin

  $("a#submit").on('click', function(e) { // capture the anchor link click
      e.preventDefault();                 // block default anchor link behaviors
      $("#myform").submit();              // simulates a submit button
  });
  ```
- Use an `href="#"` within the anchor tag.

  ```
  <a id="submit" href="#">Submit</a>
  ```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myform").validate({ // initialize plugin
    submitHandler: function(form) { // simulate form submission for demo
      alert('form submission');
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("a#submit").on('click', function(e) { // capture the anchor link click
    e.preventDefault();                 // block default anchor link behaviors
    $("#myform").submit();              // simulates a submit button
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" required="required" name="test1" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" required="required" name="test2" />
  <br />
  <a id="submit" href="#">Submit</a>
</form>
```