# Use jQuery validation on anchor tag click

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use jQuery validation on anchor tag click event. Here is my HTML form and jquery

HTML Form :

```
<form name="search_booking" id="search_booking" action="get_booking_by_cust_name.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="job_date" id="job_date">
          <a id="submit" style="cursor: pointer" >Search</a>
</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $("#search_booking").validate({
                rules: {
                    job_date: {required: true}
                },
                messages: {
                    job_date: {
                        required: "Please provide job date."
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

After clicking on anchor tag it will not submitting form to the form action.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it's working code or not? What is the issue?

Comment: put a href="#" in the anchor tag

Comment: Also due to `.validate({})` inside click event handler, validation is initialized on every click. It's definitely not good idea.

Comment: Duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8681853/594235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the validator plugin in dom ready and then in the submit button click, call the form's submit event which will do the validation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_booking").validate({
    rules: {
      job_date: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      job_date: {
        required: "Please provide job date."
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#search_booking").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form name="search_booking" id="search_booking" action="get_booking_by_cust_name.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="job_date" id="job_date">
  <a id="submit" style="cursor: pointer">Search</a>
</form>
```

Comment: @VishalKulkarni & Arun, it would be a very good idea to use the `event.preventDefault()` within the `click` handler along with an `href="#"` to keep the HTML standards compliant.   Otherwise, you'll probably get a page jump and the click will go into the browser history.  After all, you're not using the anchor link as it was designed, so you might as well stop all of its default behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the accepted answer except for two things...

- I'm using an [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to block the default behaviors of the anchor element.

  ```
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#search_booking").submit();
  });
  ```
- I've added a `href="#"` so that the jump to the top of the page can be properly blocked by the `.preventDefault()`, as well as to maintain HTML standards compliance.

  ```
  <a id="submit" href="#" style="cursor: pointer">Search</a>
  ```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_booking").validate({
    rules: {
      job_date: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      job_date: {
        required: "Please provide job date."
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      // form.submit(); //default plugin behavior
      alert('submission');  // only for demo
    }
  });

  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#search_booking").submit();
  });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form name="search_booking" id="search_booking" action="get_booking_by_cust_name.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="job_date" id="job_date">
  <a id="submit" href="#" style="cursor: pointer">Search</a>
</form>
```